# SQL Query X Days back excluding date ranges (Confusing!)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, I have a tough SQL query, and I'm not sure how to go about writing it.

I am summing the number of "*bananas collected*" by an employee within the last X days, but what I could really use help on is determining **X**.

The *"last X days"* value is defined to be the last 100 days that the employee was *NOT* out due to Purple Fever, starting from some `ChosenDate` (we'll say today, 6/24/14). That is to say, if the person was sick with Purple Fever for 3 days, then I want to look back over  the last 103 days from `ChosenDate` rather than the last 100 days. Any other reason the employee may have been out does not affect our calculation.

```
Table PersonOutIncident 
+----------------------+----------+-------------+
| PersonOutIncidentID  | PersonID | ReasonOut   |
+----------------------+----------+-------------+
|                    1 | Sarah    | PurpleFever |
|                    2 | Sarah    | PaperCut    |
|                    3 | Jon      | PurpleFever |
|                    4 | Sarah    | PurpleFever |
+----------------------+----------+-------------+

Table PersonOutDetail
+-------------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
| PersonOutDetailID | PersonOutIncidentID  | BeginDate |  EndDate  |
+-------------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|                 1 |                    1 | 1/1/2014  | 1/3/2014  |
|                 2 |                    1 | 1/7/2014  | 1/13/2014 |
|                 3 |                    2 | 2/1/2014  | 2/3/2014  |
|                 4 |                    3 | 1/15/2014 | 1/20/2014 |
|                 5 |                    4 | 5/1/2014  | 5/15/2014 |
+-------------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

The tables are established. Many `PersonOutDetail` records can be associated with one `PersonOutIncident` record and there may be multiple `PersonOutIncident` records for a single employee (That is to say, there could be two or three `PersonOutIncident` records with an identical `ReasonOut` column, because they represent a particular incident or event and the not-necessarily-continuous days lost due to that particular incident)

The nature of this requirement complicates things, even conceptually to me.

The best I can think of is to check for a `BeginDate`/`EndDate` pair within the 100 day base period, then determine the number of days from `BeginDate` to `EndDate` and add that to the base 100 days. But then I would have to  check again that this new range doesn't overlap or contain additional BeginDate/EndDate pairs and add, if so, add those days as well. I can tell already that this isn't the method I want to use, but I can't wrap my mind quite around how exactly what I need to start/structure this query. Does anyone have an idea that might steer me in the correct direction? I realize this might not be clear and I apologize if I'm just confusing things.

Comment: Bananas and purple fever == Homework.

Comment: Not homework. It's my attempt at massively simplifying my tables... and I guess being a Lame Nancy in the process, sorry. This is a small part of a lengthy stored procedure I'm writing, but my experience is somewhat minimal in the area. Any clue you could give me is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to work with a table or `WITH CLAUSE` that contains a list of days. Let's say `days` is a table with one column that contains the last 200 days. (This means the query will break if the employee had more than 100 sick days in the last 200 days).

Now you can get a list of all working days of an employee like this (replace `?` with the employee id):

```
WITH t1 AS
(
    SELECT day,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY day DESC) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM days d
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PersonOutDetail pd
          INNER JOIN PersonOutIncidentID po ON po.PersonOutIncidentID = pd.PersonOutIncidentID
          WHERE d.day BETWEEN pd.BeginDate AND pd.EndDate
          AND po.ReasonOut = 'PurpleFever'
          AND po.PersonID = ?)
)
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE RowNumber <= 100;
```

Alternatively, you can obtain the '100th day' by replacing `RowNumber <= 100` with `RowNumber = 100`.